# How to implement Geo location search by text in cordova project?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

In my project I want to implement geo location which can search by typing address name. And should navigate to the address from my current location. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but there is a [Google maps plugin for cordova](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps). In the documentation, under "Map", they have a visual example of a text type-in search. Perhaps that will work for you.

You could also use the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) directly. That may be the more flexible solution.